# Cron job execute backup.bash

Tags: cron

I wish to let cron executes delete_snapshot.bash, but when I try to create cron as below:
***/1 * * * * /var/www/mango_gis/delete_snapshot.bash >/dev/null**
It didn't execute my script at all, because when I didn't see it delete the snapshot in the amazon cloud, and my script is already tested with bash, it work fine.

Here is my script as below:

```
#!/bin/bash

get()
{
    local pos=$1
    shift
    eval 'echo ${'$pos'}';
}

length(){ echo $#; }

find_snapshots()
{
    echo $(ec2-describe-snapshots | xargs -n1 basename);
}

snapshots=$(find_snapshots)
len=$(length $snapshots)
row_count=$(($len/6))

if(($row_count > 6)); then
    delete_count=$(($row_count-6))
    for (( i=1; i<=$delete_count; i++ )); do
            ec2-delete-snapshot $(echo $(get $((2+$((6*$(($i-1)))))) $snapshots)) > /dev/null
    done
fi
```

In above, I have found the problem is that I call one command of EC2 command.
I have tested to create one cron job to call this command is ec2-describe-snapshots, 
but it doesn't work.

Please advise...

Leakhina

Comment: How do you know it "didn't execute [the] script at all?"  You throw away stdout twice -- once in your crontab and once in the script itself -- perhaps the script *is* executing but some other error is discarded or missed.

What does your `crond` log say?  Where do `crond` errors go?  Does another, trivial cronjob get run (e.g., `*/1 * * * * logger -p daemon.err -- "I am a cronjob"`)?

Comment: I know that it didn't execute the script because I didn't delete the snapshot that I want to delete from the amazon cloud computing, so it didn't work. Any way how can I view cron log?

Comment: you can define the logfile using "cron" in your syslog.conf

Answer (score 1):

you should add the program with which you want to process this file; something like:

```
*/1 * * * * /bin/bash  /var/www/mango_gis/delete_snapshot.bash > /dev/null
```

using the full path is important, because you do not have the environment variables loaded when cron starts the process

Comment: I have changed it to like this 

*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/bash /var/www/mango_gis/delete_snapshot.bash >/dev/null

but it didn't work.

Comment: you may use "which bash" on commandline to find out the location of your bash program. then put this absolute path into your cron job. (location of programs differ from system to system, for example i got the bash program under /bin/bash (from your edit it looks like your absolute path to bash is the same))

Comment: please copy/paste your command (everything afer the wildcards) to your commandline and tell us what happens (does it work propperly?)

Comment: I copy /bin/bash  /var/www/mango_gis/delete_snapshot.bash > /dev/null and past it to my command, it worked fine.

Comment: in that case your program is fine - check cron using the cronlog. Does any other cronjob get executed? you can for example place a very simple one there

Comment: now I know the problem, the problem is that in delete_snapshot.bash, I have called ec2 command is ec2-describe-snapshots,and it doesn't work when I create one cron job to execute this ec2-describe-snapshots command and redirect the result to log file, but it doesn't work. have you ever created cron job to execute ec2-describe-snapshots of amazon cloud?

Comment: never used ec2-describe-snapshots at all, but it is running from commandline so i guess it is possible to make it work (maybe you miss some environment variables when executed via cron)

Comment: for changing the cron environment there are some helpfull hints to be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135478/how-to-simulate-the-environment-cron-executes-a-script-with

Answer (score 1):

thanks for your help so far.
Now I can catch it.

the problem is that cron not load the env variable so we just need to specify what we use to env variable while cron executing.
here is my test code for ec2 command as below:

export EC2_PRIVATE_KEY=/root/keys/pk-Q4NR5FGDTSWWK65EDSIDCBTEQWJ6G24V.pem
export EC2_CERT=/root/keys/cert-Q4NR5FGDTSWWK65EDSIDCBTEQWJ6G24V.pem
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/
export EC2_HOME_BIN=/usr/bin

echo "start ec2-describe-snapshots" >> /var/log/ec2-delete-snapshot.log
$EC2_HOME_BIN/ec2-describe-snapshots >> /var/log/ec2-delete-snapshot.log
echo "end it" >> /var/log/ec2-delete-snapshot.log

Comment: that is exactly what i was talking about yesterday in the other comments to my answer (you need to push "show x more comments" to see them)