# Run Python Script - Cron

Tags: python, cron

How can I run a python script once at exactly 12:00PM on Wednesday (Jan 21)?

I've added `#!/usr/bin/env python` to the top of my script and made the script executable with `chmod +x`

I know I want to do something like `crontab -e 0 0 * * * /path/to/my/pythonscript.py` but I'm not exactly sure how to get it to be a specific time...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to setup cron to run a file just once at a specific time in future?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473780/how-to-setup-cron-to-run-a-file-just-once-at-a-specific-time-in-future)

Comment: @JoelHinz How would I get this to be March 30 at 1PM?    0 0 30 3 ? 2011

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python script is not running under cron, despite working when run manually](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6363023/608639).

Answer (score 1):

To run on 21 Jan at 12pm you will need the following line in your crontab file:
`0 12 21 1 * /path/to/my/pythonscript`

Edit the crontab file with `crontab -e`

The first number is *minute*, the second number is *hour*, the third one *day of month*, the fourth *month*, the fifth is *day of week* (in this case a * for any day of week), then the path.

The [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) on Cron is really helpful if you want to change the times.