# VSQL is generating output file using perl script but not in cronjob

Tags: sql, perl, cron, vertica, vsql

i have created the perl script in which i am connecting to vsql and running queries. when i run the script mannually, it is creating output files as expected. but when i set this script in crontab then output file is not generating. perl script is given below

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$timenow = `date "+%H_%M"`;
chomp($timenow);
$cmd = "/opt/vertica/bin/vsql -d xxxx-U xxxxx -w xxxxx -F \$'--FSEP--' -At -o dumpfile_" . $timenow . ".txt -c \"SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(1) AS time;\"";
print "$cmd\n";
system($cmd);
```

and below is the contab entry

```
*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/perl /tmp/test.pl
```

can somebody please help what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341324/perl-script-works-but-not-via-cron?rq=1 check this Question.

Comment: Crontab runs in own environment. There is a high chance that `perl` is not included into default `PATH`. Looking at your script you could do same with default shell instead of `perl`.

Comment: @PolarBear - how do i check if perl is included into default path ? below is the bash profile of user which owns the crontab 
`cat .bash_profile
# .bash_profile
# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi
# User specific environment and startup programs
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/vertica/bin:/opt/vertica/sbin
export PATH
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF8"
export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
`

Comment: You can create a cron job with following command `env > /tmp/cronjob.out` and verify what variables are set in this file.

Answer (score 2):

Your output is written to a file called `dumpfile_[timestamp].txt`. But where is that file?

Your command contains no directory path for that file. So it will be written to the current directory. The current directory for a cronjob is the home directory for the user that owns the cronjob. Have you tried looking there?

It's always better to be more specific about which directory you want the files written to. Two ways to do that are:

1. Change to the directory before running your command
   `*/2 * * * * cd /some_directory_path && /usr/bin/perl /tmp/test.pl`
2. Include the full path in your Perl program
   `-o /some_directory_path/dumpfile_" . $timenow . ".txt`

**Update:** Ok, take two.

Who owns this cronjob? Any output from the cronjob will be emailed to the owner. And there's definitely output as you have a `print()` statement. Any errors will be included in the same email. Do you get that email? What's in it?

If you don't get the email, you can change the address that the email is sent to by adding a `MAILTO` parameter to the crontab. It will look like this:

```
MAILTO=someone@example.com
*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/perl /tmp/test.pl
```

Bear in mind that the server might not be set up to send external email, so you might need to use the local `mail` program on the server.

If you can't get the email to work out, you could look for cron errors in `/var/log/syslog` (or, on a `systemd` system, try `journalctl _COMM=cron`).

The `print()` output is going somewhere. You need to track it down.

Comment: i have modified the script and provided complete path for output `-o /tmp/dumpfile_" . $timenow . ".txt` @Dave. but results are same. still no file is generated.

Comment: @veerkumarrathore: See my update

Comment: dbadmin is the owner of crontab. and i dont see any error in cron log.
Oct  3 03:10:01 xxxxxxxx CROND[522079]: (dbadmin) CMD (/usr/bin/perl /data/backups/bin/backData.pl)

Comment: @veerkumarrathore: Have you found where the `print()` output goes to yet?

Comment: i finally captured the cron log and found error (given below). `vsql: unsupported locale character encoding
  use a utf8 locale, not a ISO-8859-1 locale`

Comment: @veerkumarrathore: This might be useful to you - https://www.logikdev.com/2010/02/02/locale-settings-for-your-cron-job/

Comment: now i have added this line in top of script. lets hope this works this time. `$ENV{'LANG'}  =  "en_US.UTF-8";`