# How to start a shell without any user configuration?

Tags: linux, macos, bash, shell

I need to use a "clean" shell (e.g. bash) under Linux/OSX terminal without any user configuration, but it reads config info from some files (e.g ~/.bashrc) every time it starts. I can modify the file every time I need a "clean" shell, and revert it back when I finished, but is there any easier ways to do this, for example a command?

Comment: The answers provided below are also useful when, say, one makes a mistake in their `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` files that causes the shell to exit prematurely.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can pass the `--noprofile` and `--norc` command-line options:

```
$ bash --noprofile --norc
```

You will find documentation about these options in the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash).

Comment: `bash --noprofile --norc` still inherits from parent process.

Comment: This was good enough for me. Got rid of my aliases, prompts, etc.

Comment: `env -i PATH=/usr/bin:/bin "TERM=$TERM" "HOME=$HOME" bash --noprofile --norc`

Comment: In order to also avoid any configuration files and dirs from the home directory (`.condarc`, `.gitconfig`, etc.) you also need a new temporary empty home directory, as per my [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70993014/758174).

Answer (score 158):

Running `bash --noprofile --norc` still inherited from parent process.  Based on a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135478/how-to-simulate-the-environment-cron-executes-a-script-with) I found that the way I interpreted this question `env -i bash --norc --noprofile` was what I would want.

Comment: Thanks for the `env -i` tip! This ended up being a little *too* clean for me, since I just wanted to get rid of my custom settings, but I still needed the system-wide settings. This is what I ended up using: `env -i bash --rcfile /etc/profile`

Comment: Great tip.  The "env -i" is exactly what I needed.  My bash_profile was still being read in despite the "--noprofile --norc" .

Comment: You didn't need the argument --noprofile as it's only relevant if you have a login shell.

Comment: It still inherits the `history`.

Comment: What's the difference between `env -i bash --norc --noprofile` and `bash --norc --noprofile`?

Comment: @thc according to man page, `-i, --ignore-environment start with an empty environment`

Comment: Note that the usage of `env` in the answer executes the 'system Bash' and not necessarily the one you expect.  Using `env -i $(which bash) --norc --noprofile` may result in a better outcome, depending on your setup.  Also note that starting a shell without your profile settings may have unintended consequences, such as clearing or truncating your shell history file.

Answer (score 9):

Use --noprofile --norc:

```
   --noprofile
          Do  not  read either the system-wide startup file /etc/profile or any of the personal initializa‐
          tion files ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, or ~/.profile.  By default,  bash  reads  these  files
          when it is invoked as a login shell (see INVOCATION below).

   --norc Do  not  read  and  execute the system wide initialization file /etc/bash.bashrc and the personal
          initialization file ~/.bashrc if the shell is interactive.  This option is on by default  if  the
          shell is invoked as sh.
```

(from the manpage).

Answer (score 7):

It is often desirable to launch an entirely blank bash:

- no environment variables carried from the parent shell;
- an empty home dir without any package-specific configuration files (e.g. `.gitconfig` and `.local/...`);
- no shell configuration files.

This works for me both on MacOS and Linux:

```sh
env -i HOME=$(mktemp -d) bash --noprofile --norc
cd
```

In that bash shell, the `HOME` dir is that test dir just created (change the name if needed), and there are no particular settings.  The only environment variables that are set are `PWD`, `HOME`, and `SHLVL`.

Upon starting bash, the `PWD` is where we were before, so we need to do that initial `cd`.

Example (Linux):

```sh
$ env -i HOME=$(mktemp -d) bash --noprofile --norc
bash-5.0$ cd
bash-5.0$ pwd
/tmp/tmp.mwgHRQE1aJ
bash-5.0$ printenv
PWD=/tmp/tmp.mwgHRQE1aJ
HOME=/tmp/tmp.mwgHRQE1aJ
SHLVL=1
OLDPWD=/home/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
_=/usr/bin/printenv
bash-5.0$
```