# Run last command in Bash broken (!!)

Tags: bash

Somehow my bash rc scripts (which are hundreds of lines long and non-trivial to review) are breaking `!!` and I'm not sure how to quickly debug it. I know this because when I [run bash with no user config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357464/how-to-start-a-shell-without-any-user-configuration) it works fine. How can I debug this quickly, or does anything come to mind? I'm not running this in a script -- I'm typing from the command line.

```
$ !!
!!: command not found

$ echo $-
himBs

$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)


$ shopt
autocd          off
cdable_vars     off
cdspell         off
checkhash       off
checkjobs       off
checkwinsize    off
cmdhist         on
compat31        off
compat32        off
compat40        off
compat41        off
compat42        off
compat43        off
complete_fullquote  on
direxpand       off
dirspell        off
dotglob         off
execfail        off
expand_aliases  on
extdebug        off
extglob         on
extquote        on
failglob        off
force_fignore   on
globasciiranges off
globstar        off
gnu_errfmt      off
histappend      off
histreedit      off
histverify      off
hostcomplete    off
huponexit       off
inherit_errexit off
interactive_comments    on
lastpipe        off
lithist         off
login_shell     on
mailwarn        off
no_empty_cmd_completion off
nocaseglob      off
nocasematch     off
nullglob        off
progcomp        on
promptvars      on
restricted_shell    off
shift_verbose   off
sourcepath      on
xpg_echo        off
```

Comment: You are _not_ running that in a script by chance? You are typing `!!` in an interactive session? Please post the output of `shopt` and `echo $-`

Comment: Correct, typing. Added those...

Comment: `$ echo $-
himBs` `H` is missing - history expansion is turned off. Do `set -H` and it will turn on.