# cd to symbolically linked directory fails in cron environment

Tags: shell, ubuntu, cron, environment-variables, cd

I have a server running Ubuntu 12.04, which we use to host a Rails app. I'm running a task on cron, which is made up of a couple of unix commands separated by `&&` - e.g:

```
cd /home/deploy/app/current && RAILS_ENV=production ...
```

The final bit has been snipped, as the command is failing on the very first `cd`, with this:

> cd: No such file or directory

In the *deploy* user's environment that cd works without a problem. The directory exists, and it's a symbolic link:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 deploy deploy 42 Mar  4 15:28 /home/deploy/app/current -> /home/deploy/app/releases/20130304152305
```

I thought it was strange that the ability for the shell to cd to a symbolic link would be affected by the environment, so I spit out the cron's environment variables to a file, according to this question: [How to simulate the environment cron executes a script with?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135478/how-to-simulate-the-environment-cron-executes-a-script-with).

If I try and execute that line as the cron user, it fails:

```
$ env - $(cat ~/cron.env) cd /home/deploy/app/current
env: cd: No such file or directory
```

Why does this happen? The cron's environment variables are:

```
HOME=/home/deploy
LOGNAME=deploy
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
SHELL=/bin/sh
PWD=/home/deploy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cd` is a shell builtin, not an program, and so neither `cron` nor `env` cannot execute it directly. The following should work for your cron job:

```
sh -c "cd /home/deploy/app/current && RAILS_ENV=production ..."
```

Comment: That makes sense with what I'm seeing. I always assumed that cron ran commands in a shell automatically, but it turns out that's not true! Thanks