# check if process is running linux shell not working

Tags: java, linux, shell

I am having a java process which needs to be always running. I have written the following shell in cron program to check that java process:

```
if [ `ps aux | grep testjava | grep -v grep | wc -l` -ne 1 ];then
cd /root/folder
sh mytest.sh >test.log 2>test-err.log &
echo "mytest not running and restarted on "`date` >> /root/check-test.log
```

where `mytest.sh` contains the java class which has to be running.

When I execute the shell file separately it executes well. But when I execute the above cron it gives me the following exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: mytest/mytestprog
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mytest.mytestprog
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Where i am going wrong .

Edit:

I run the mytest.sh file with the path as `$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -cp .:/root/lib/* -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:/root/folder/ -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=hostnameip -Djava.security.policy=server.policy -Xmx512m -Xms512m mytest.mytestprog`

Comment: I suspect that when `mytest.sh` is called, the path is not right; you are not finding the source file. Make sure the necessary environment variables are set explicitly inside your shell script.

Comment: I am having file to be run in this path /root/folder.And i have given cd /root/folder .,Is there any thing wrong in giving cd command in that cron

Comment: Does it have the right permissions to run your executables? Cron is running as what user? I would read the links that @spaceknarf has posted - their titles look very promising.

Comment: Ya it has proper permissions

Comment: Instead of playing tricks with `ps`, you'd better maintain a `.pid` file under `/var/run`. To write reliable daemons you could try out [http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/] and/or [http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/jsvc.html].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a job is executed in `cron`, it has a different environment. Most likely, your `.bashrc` is not being loaded. And often the `CLASSPATH` is set in that file. Thus, the `CLASSPATH` is probably incorrect.

For ways to set the environment in `cron`, see:

- [Where can I set environment variables that crontab will use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229825/where-can-i-set-environment-variables-that-crontab-will-use)
- [How to simulate the environment cron executes a script with?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135478/how-to-simulate-the-environment-cron-executes-a-script-with)
- [How can I run a cron command with existing environmental variables?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27289/how-can-i-run-a-cron-command-with-existing-environmental-variables)

Comment: But in mytest.sh file itself am having the path as $JAVA_HOME/bin/java  -cp .:/root/lib/*  -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:/root/folder/ -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=hostnameip -Djava.security.policy=server.policy  -Xmx512m -Xms512m  mytest.mytestprog

Comment: You could create a test program in Java that prints its class path, and see if it's different inside and outside `cron`.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than running such a long list of piped command I would suggest using pgrep:

```
[ $(pgrep -f testjava) ] &&  && echo "running"
```

Comment: That is true, but probably not the cause of his problem.