# Process stops after start in cron

Tags: bash, process, cron, webrtc

I want to start webrtc2sip from cron:

```
* * * * * root /taafs/webrtc2sip/webrtc2sip --config=/taafs/webrtc2sip/config.xml >> /var/log/webrtc2sip.log 2>&1
```

When cron runs, I see output in /var/log/webrtc2sip.log , but

```
ps aux | grep webrtc2sip
```

shows nothing.

When I run command from my root bash it shows absolutely the same output, and shows in ps aux! 
Also, when I install env from cron to new bash, and start command from this bash, it works(displayed in ps)! So the reason is not environment, but what?

Comment: What does "when I install env from cron to new bash" mean exactly? Does the command work if you run `env -i sh -c '/taafs/webrtc2sip/webrtc2sip --config=/taafs/webrtc2sip/config.xml >> /var/log/webrtc2sip.log 2>&1'`?

Comment: This means accepted answer from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135478/how-to-simulate-the-environment-cron-executes-a-script-with# . And yes, your command also works.

Comment: Have you checked the system and cron logs?

Comment: /var/log/cron shows only command (no errors)

Comment: Does `env -i sh -c 'nohup /taafs/webrtc2sip/webrtc2sip --config=/taafs/webrtc2sip/config.xml >> /var/log/webrtc2sip.log 2>&1 </dev/null'` work?

Comment: No, it doesn't, hmmm

Comment: Then that's a problem of the program when it doesn't have either standard input or a controlling terminal. You get to figure out what.

Comment: Which file (full path) do you have changed to insert your cronjob?

Comment: Which OS/distribution and version do you use?

Comment: @user3479125 at what time your `cron` runs with all *?

Comment: problem solved, now I use screen to start my program, so it think that STDIN present. Thanks to Etan Reisner for finding issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, so I resorted to creating a small patch to make console optional when starting webrtc2sip by adding a new argument, **--without-console**.

It is documented here: http://marcelog.github.io/articles/starting_webrtc2sip_as_service.html and the patch is available as a gist here: https://gist.github.com/marcelog/47ef364b43c67f9f359d

I hope it helps, it's been working great for me so far, and I use [daemontools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html) to supervise the process.

Best!