# Laravel command not working as cron

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, cron, backup

I have the below command set up for backing up

```
db:backup --database=mysql --destination=s3 --destinationPath=date +\test/%Y%m%d%H%M%S.sql--compression=gzip
```

Code works fine as command

Fails with `local.ERROR: exception 'BackupManager\ShellProcessing\ShellProcessFailed' with message 'sh: mysqldump: command not found` when the same is run from scheduler.

Any suggestions.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135478/how-to-simulate-the-environment-cron-executes-a-script-with , since I think it's related to different environment issues when running through crontab

Comment: @Amarnasan is probably right, but please post your command as well so it's easier to tell.

Comment: Hi @Amarnasan,  My scheduler works fine, since i have other scheduler commands which works fine.  Regarding the backup commans, its from laravel backup plugin https://github.com/backup-manager/laravel

Comment: Seems like a `path` problem. Try specifying `mysqldump` full path in your script: something like `/usr/bin/mysqldump`

Answer (score 0):

Yep figured out the details.

shell path was not initialised when running as cron

Solution was to create as shell script and call it from cron with bash_profile initiated before cron

crontab

```
* * * * * bash /path/cron.sh
```

cron.sh

```
. .bash_profile
<cron command>
```