# cronjob unable to get the sqlalchemy library

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, sqlalchemy, cron

```
import requests  
import json  
import Credential  
import psycopg2   
from sqlalchemy import
```

I am using `“sqlalchemy”` library as shown above to stored value into the database. The program running successfully when i run from command prompt eg. `"python filename.py"`. But i need to run program after specific interval of time. So, I created the shell file and set the **cronjob** to run the shell file for specific time as below:

```
15 16 22 7 * /home/ubuntu/Clio-Python/new_clio_shell.sh
```

But the cron not getting sqlalchemy library. So how should I import this library in the crontab? Should I need to import path in the cron file? If yes how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Importing path the cron file should work, but you can go one further and import your whole environment.

> Add this to your cron:
>
> 30 08 * * * env > ~/cronenv After it runs, do this:
>
> env - `cat ~/cronenv` /bin/sh This assumes that your cron runs sh. I
>   believe this is the default.

Original solution by [mmccoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23630/mmccoo) can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135478/how-to-simulate-the-environment-cron-executes-a-script-with).