# pfSense cron job not running or no output

Tags: cron, pfsense

Hope someone can help me out here.

I've written a python script that I want to run under CRON every 5 minutes. 
In keeping with the general security practice of least privilege, I:

- created a user "custom" to use for custom scripts
- created a group "custom" (don't want anything running under nobody to have 
  access) and;
- put the script (monitor) in /home/custom/bin

The shebang in the script is:

**#!/usr/bin/env python2.7**

The only permission given to user custom is:

```
Inherited from   Name   Description                  Action
                User - System: Shell account access   Indicates whether the user is able to login for example via SSH.
```

Running the script with the command **/home/custom/bin/monitor** from the command line works regardless of the current working directory.

I tried doing cd / first to make sure it wasn't a path issue, and the script ran correctly.

The script writes 2 files on the first run, and subsequent runs append to those files in the directory /home/custom/bin/mondata

I installed the CRON package and created the following entry:

***/5    *    *    *    *    custom    /home/custom/bin/monitor**

(There doesn't seem to be an "Apply Changes", so I'm assuming that I don't need to reboot or do anything to load the changes.)
(The above entry and many others are displayed in the WebGUI, and I know that several of those other cron jobs are running.)

After waiting for enough time for the script to run, I checked for output and there was nothing.

Changing custom to root for testing purposes (Just in case the issue was a permission problem) doesn't fix the problem.

Here are the relevant file permissions:

```
[2.3.2-RELEASE][custom@local]/home/custom/bin: ls -laR ~
total 52
drwxr-xr-x  4 custom  nobody   512 Aug  7 00:14 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 root    wheel    512 Jul 27 15:24 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 custom  custom   512 Aug  7 00:14 bin

/home/custom/bin:
total 20
drwxr-xr-x  3 custom  custom   512 Aug  7 00:14 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 custom  nobody   512 Aug  7 00:14 ..
drwxrwx---  2 custom  custom   512 Aug  7 00:07 mondata    <-Script output goes here
-rwxr-xr-x  1 custom  custom  4663 Aug  5 22:44 monitor    <-The script

/home/custom/bin/mondata:
total 8
drwxrwx---  2 custom  custom  512 Aug  7 00:07 .           <-NO OUTPUT! (I deleted the files manually after successful tests)
drwxr-xr-x  3 custom  custom  512 Aug  7 00:14 ..
```

I checked for an error message in: **Status / System / Logs / System / General** - Nothing found.

I even tried temporarily changing the permissions on /home/custom/bin/mondata to 777 and setting the cron user to root
(totally unacceptable security practice just for testing, but even that didn't work.)

I have no way of knowing if the script is running and the file writes are being denied for some reason, or if the script isn't running at all.

**BTW, where is the cron tab?**  When I run crontab -l as root, I get crontab: no crontab for root, but I KNOW cron jobs are running. 
(I have the daily mail report running.)

Any suggestions - even for troubleshooting to know if the script is running would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: If you install the 'Cron' package on pfsense, then you can view/edit the cronjobs from 'Services -> Cron' from the web interface.

Comment: An the big question: how to see cron logs from the web interface?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that python was not executing.

The so called "portable" shebang that worked at the command line -

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
```

- DOES NOT WORK from cron.

I created the following file as /home/custom/bin/tcron

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
import os
os.system('/usr/local/bin/minicron')
```

When run from the command line, it put the minicron error into the log every time it is run, but did nothing when run from cron.

I changed #!/usr/bin/env python2.7 to #!/usr/local/bin/python2.7, and now it works.

I don't know if this is intentional that #!/usr/bin/env python2.7 doesn't work from cron, but for now I'm not going to worry about it.

I hope by documenting this it might save somebody else the same trouble, and if it's a bug that should be reported, someone who knows how to do that will do so.

Comment: I think the problem is that cron can use a different `$PATH` from your login shell, which doesn't contain `python2.7`, so `env` won't find it.  You can check your cron environment with https://stackoverflow.com/a/2546509/446106