# different ssh behavior from crond

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, cron, centos

I've been pulling my hair out on this one for several hours now. I welcome any new ideas on where to look next.

The objective is to login to a custom application CLI over SSH and then drop down a debug shell on the far-end device using one of the custom CLI commands. On the client side I'm using CentOS minimal and running ssh as follows:

Working case:

```
[user@ashleys-xpvm ws]$ ssh -p8222 admin@192.168.56.20

admin@192.168.56.20's password:  
Welcome to CLI
admin connected from 172.29.33.108 using ssh on scm2 
TRAN39# debug-utils shell 
device@scm2:~$
```

The ssh client session accesses the custom CLI using the application-specific port 8222. Once inside the CLI, we drop down to the bash shell using the 'debug-utils shell' command.

This sequence was scripted with Python/pexpect and that worked fine when the script was launched from the user's command line. The problem arose when the script was moved to the crontab to be run automatically by crond. In the latter case, the script fails in a peculiar way.

Following the recommendation from this post: [How to simulate the environment cron executes a script with?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135478/how-to-simulate-the-environment-cron-executes-a-script-with) I launched a new shell on the client machine with the same environment variables as what the cron job uses and I was able to manually reproduce the same problem that the automatic cron job was running into.

With the cron environment set, the far-end device now throws the following error at the point where we issue the command to drop into the device's bash shell:

```
sh-4.2$ ssh -p8222 admin@192.168.56.20

admin@192.168.56.20's password: 
Welcome to CLI
admin connected from 172.29.33.108 using ssh on scm2
TRAN39# debug-utils shell
error: failed to decode arguments
TRAN39#
```

Once I had the problem reproduced, I setup two terminals, one with the working environment variables and the other with the failing environment variables. I ran ssh from both terminals with '-vvv' flag  and compared the debug output between the two.

The two outputs were identical except for where they step through the environment variables to determine what to send to the send the SSH server (obviously), as well as the 'bits set' lines were slightly different. I looked at the environment variable lines and I could see that ssh is ignoring all of them except for LANG which is identical in both the working case and the failing case.

I'm at a loss now for why the ssh server at the far-end device is behaving differently between these two client-side environment settings.

Here is the working environment:

```
[user@centos_vm ws]$ env
XDG_SESSION_ID=294
HOSTNAME=centos_vm
SELINUX_ROLE_REQUESTED=
TERM=xterm-256color
SHELL=/bin/bash
HISTSIZE=1000
SSH_CLIENT=192.168.56.20 52795 22
SELINUX_USE_CURRENT_RANGE=
OLDPWD=/home/user
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/4
USER=user
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=38;5;27:ln=38;5;51:mh=44;38;5;15:pi=40;38;5;11:so=38;5;13:do=38;5;5:bd=48;5;232;38;5;11:cd=48;5;232;38;5;3:or=48;5;232;38;5;9:mi=05;48;5;232;38;5;15:su=48;5;196;38;5;15:sg=48;5;11;38;5;16:ca=48;5;196;38;5;226:tw=48;5;10;38;5;16:ow=48;5;10;38;5;21:st=48;5;21;38;5;15:ex=38;5;34:*.tar=38;5;9:*.tgz=38;5;9:*.arc=38;5;9:*.arj=38;5;9:*.taz=38;5;9:*.lha=38;5;9:*.lz4=38;5;9:*.lzh=38;5;9:*.lzma=38;5;9:*.tlz=38;5;9:*.txz=38;5;9:*.tzo=38;5;9:*.t7z=38;5;9:*.zip=38;5;9:*.z=38;5;9:*.Z=38;5;9:*.dz=38;5;9:*.gz=38;5;9:*.lrz=38;5;9:*.lz=38;5;9:*.lzo=38;5;9:*.xz=38;5;9:*.bz2=38;5;9:*.bz=38;5;9:*.tbz=38;5;9:*.tbz2=38;5;9:*.tz=38;5;9:*.deb=38;5;9:*.rpm=38;5;9:*.jar=38;5;9:*.war=38;5;9:*.ear=38;5;9:*.sar=38;5;9:*.rar=38;5;9:*.alz=38;5;9:*.ace=38;5;9:*.zoo=38;5;9:*.cpio=38;5;9:*.7z=38;5;9:*.rz=38;5;9:*.cab=38;5;9:*.jpg=38;5;13:*.jpeg=38;5;13:*.gif=38;5;13:*.bmp=38;5;13:*.pbm=38;5;13:*.pgm=38;5;13:*.ppm=38;5;13:*.tga=38;5;13:*.xbm=38;5;13:*.xpm=38;5;13:*.tif=38;5;13:*.tiff=38;5;13:*.png=38;5;13:*.svg=38;5;13:*.svgz=38;5;13:*.mng=38;5;13:*.pcx=38;5;13:*.mov=38;5;13:*.mpg=38;5;13:*.mpeg=38;5;13:*.m2v=38;5;13:*.mkv=38;5;13:*.webm=38;5;13:*.ogm=38;5;13:*.mp4=38;5;13:*.m4v=38;5;13:*.mp4v=38;5;13:*.vob=38;5;13:*.qt=38;5;13:*.nuv=38;5;13:*.wmv=38;5;13:*.asf=38;5;13:*.rm=38;5;13:*.rmvb=38;5;13:*.flc=38;5;13:*.avi=38;5;13:*.fli=38;5;13:*.flv=38;5;13:*.gl=38;5;13:*.dl=38;5;13:*.xcf=38;5;13:*.xwd=38;5;13:*.yuv=38;5;13:*.cgm=38;5;13:*.emf=38;5;13:*.axv=38;5;13:*.anx=38;5;13:*.ogv=38;5;13:*.ogx=38;5;13:*.aac=38;5;45:*.au=38;5;45:*.flac=38;5;45:*.mid=38;5;45:*.midi=38;5;45:*.mka=38;5;45:*.mp3=38;5;45:*.mpc=38;5;45:*.ogg=38;5;45:*.ra=38;5;45:*.wav=38;5;45:*.axa=38;5;45:*.oga=38;5;45:*.spx=38;5;45:*.xspf=38;5;45:
MAIL=/var/spool/mail/user
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/user/.local/bin:/home/user/bin
PWD=/home/user/ws
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
SELINUX_LEVEL_REQUESTED=
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
SHLVL=1
HOME=/home/user
LOGNAME=user
SSH_CONNECTION=192.168.56.20 52795 192.168.56.101 22
LESSOPEN=||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
_=/usr/bin/env
[user@centos_vm ws]$
```

...and here is the failing (i.e. cron) environment:

```
sh-4.2$ env
XDG_SESSION_ID=321
SHELL=/bin/sh
USER=user
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
PWD=/home/user/ws
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
HOME=/home/user
SHLVL=2
LOGNAME=user
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
_=/usr/bin/env
OLDPWD=/home/user
sh-4.2$
```

I'm running out of my depth on ssh debugging at this point so any guidance on where to look next is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if it's your problem or not, but I'd set PATH in the script/program being run by cron.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I tried that already but I will try it again and confirm back.

Comment: As I thought, it does not make a difference. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Not sure ssh will accept to take input for password without a try (I might be wrong on that). You could use an ssh key instead. If you really need to use a password, maybe try that within a tmux session.

Comment: the password is accepted fine in both cases. The issue comes after the password when the 'debug-utils shell' command is issued. There's something going wrong with how the server at the far-end is parsing that command triggered by the difference in environment settings on the near-end. It's very strange.

Comment: Got you, sorry. So the CLI tool is something proprietary, and `debug-utils shell` is a command interpreted by that proprietary tool? If so, what details can you share about this? (Language/framework...). This might have to do with the absence of tty (not at password input time, alright, but maybe something your tool expects)

Comment: Suggestion (attempt to simplify problem space) : if you try to run your CLI + command in a cron task _on the remote machine_, does that work? If that also fails, it will remove ssh from the equation.

Comment: @Denis Also note that when run from cron commands are run in /bin/sh. At the command line your user is running in /bin/bash. Again, may not make a big difference, but try ensuring the cron job is executed in bash (or perhaps `bash -l`).

Comment: @Denis -- could you try setting `TERM=xterm` in  crontab?

Comment: I would first try setting `TERM` as already suggested, and then try adding the `-t` option to ssh (`ssh -t ...`).

Comment: @JohnZwinck -- just tried and `-t` is not necessary. seems like `-t` is implied when login and start the remote interactive login shell (`ssh user@host`).

Comment: @Deathgrip, thanks, but I had already confirmed that /bin/sh on my client machine is soft linked to /bin/bash so the interpreter is the same in both cron and on command line.

Comment: @whjm Bingo!, TERM=xterm in the cron environment did the trick! Thanks so much.

Comment: Glad it's figured out. But FYI don't assume /bin/sh and /bin/bash will behave identically because /bin/sh is a symlink to /bin/bash. On some older Unix systems cp, rm, and mv were all the same executable (hard links though, shared the same inode), yet did much different things based on how it was invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually `ssh` without specifying a command (`ssh user@host`) would pass the value of `TERM` on local host to remote server. For example:

```
# TERM=foo ssh 127.0.0.1
bash-4.4# echo $TERM
foo
bash-4.4#
```

In crontab, `crond` by default will not set the `TERM` var so after ssh login, the `TERM` will be set to `dumb` (which is not fully functional). See example:

```
# (unset TERM; ssh 127.0.0.1)
bash-4.4# echo $TERM
dumb
bash-4.4# clear
TERM environment variable not set.
bash-4.4#
```

In your case it sounds like the remote application requires a more functional `TERM` so explicitly setting it to `TERM=xterm` (which will be passed to the remote server) in crontab would fix it.

**Note** that `ssh` with a command (`ssh user@host command...`) will not allocate a pty on remote server so the local `TERM` will not be passed. To force creating a pty and passing the var we must use `ssh -t`. See example:

```
# echo $TERM
dtterm
# ssh 127.0.0.1 'tty; echo $TERM'
not a tty
dumb
# ssh -t 127.0.0.1 'tty; echo $TERM'
/dev/pts/8
dtterm
#
```

---

Found *Dumb terminals* on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal):

> Dumb terminals are those that can interpret a **limited** number of control codes (`CR`, `LF`, etc.) but do not have the ability to process special escape sequences that perform functions such as clearing a line, clearing the screen, or controlling cursor position. In this context dumb terminals are sometimes dubbed glass Teletypes, for they essentially have the same limited functionality as does a mechanical Teletype. This type of dumb terminal is still supported on modern Unix-like systems by setting the environment variable `TERM` to `dumb`. Smart or intelligent terminals are those that also have the ability to process escape sequences, in particular the `VT52`, `VT100` or `ANSI` escape sequences.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. it's working like a charm with TERM=term passed in to the crontab invocation.