# .expect script runs when called manually but not by .service

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, service, expect

On a Ubuntu 16.04.2 server, I have a simple expect script  `/etc/pipes.expect` to setup vm routing through the server's ports.

Here is the content of `/etc/pipes.expect`:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
sleep 60
spawn virsh start lucas
spawn virsh start ssix-project
spawn virsh start allsorter
sleep 300 #some time to boot the vms
spawn ssh -f -N -L [my_ip]:22003:localhost:22 lucas@ssix-project
expect  "*assword:*" { send "[pass1]\r" }
expect  "*yes/no*" {
            send "yes\r"
            expect  "*assword:*" { send "[pass1]\r" }
        }
spawn ssh -f -N -L [my_ip]:22004:localhost:22 lucas@allsorter
expect  "*assword:*" { send "[pass2]\r" }
expect  "*yes/no*" {
            send "yes\r"
            expect "*assword:*" { send "[pass2]\r"}
        }
spawn ssh -f -N -L [my_ip]:22002:localhost:22 lucas@lucas
expect  "*assword:*" { send "pass3\r" }
expect  "*yes/no*" {
            send "yes\r"
            expect "*assword:*" { send "pass\r"}
        }
```

The script runs perfectly if I call it with:

`/etc/pipes.expect` , `expect /etc/pipes.expect` or `/usr/bin/expect /etc/pipes.expect`

But the `ssh` calls don't take effect when `pipes.expect` is called via `pipes.service`. What bugs me is that the `virsh` calls(lines 3 to 5) work when the script is called manually or by the service.

Here is the content of my `pipes.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Spark service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/expect /etc/pipes.expect


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

P.S.: I've tried many methods of making this script run on boot, including init.d, crontab, rc.local and nothing seems to work :(. Can anyone light things over here a bit?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the difference between your personal environment and the environment of the service (user, path, etc)

Comment: try setting `TERM=xterm` and see if it works. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44221559/different-ssh-behavior-from-crond

Comment: @glennjackman `printenv` on the script gives me only `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` and `PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`. PATH is exactly the same as in my personal env.

Comment: @whjm I'm doing 
`set ::env(TERM) /usr/bin/xterm`
`send_user "$env(TERM)\n"`

at the start of my `.expect` script, still, ssh are called but the routing is not set.

Comment: `TERM=xterm`, not `TERM=/usr/bin/xterm`

Comment: @whjm same results. `xterm` resolves to `/usr/bin/xterm`

Comment: any error messages?

Comment: @whjm that's the worst. nothing at all. the service exits with code 0

Comment: The verbose output is also the same, when the script is called either manually or by the service.