# bash script runs standalone but not with cron

Tags: bash, cron

I know you get this a lot, but i couldn't get this code to work in cron. even though it runs stand alone.
i am trying to ssh to server, get last redmine backup file, encrypt it with gpg public key, copy it over to local backup computer, delete encrypted file and exit.

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh user@192.168.1.131 'cd /data/redmine/redmine/data/backups; file=$(ls -t | head -1); gpg --always-trust --encrypt --recipient 2E87B5C4E322C0AFCD1113EFCBB7C68 $file; enc_file=$(ls *.gpg); scp $enc_file user@192.168.1.129:/backups/redmineBackups/backups; rm $enc_file'
```

my crontab looks like this

```
* * * * * /scripts/redmineEncrpt.sh
```

trying to run it every minute for testing. cron runs it but never get the result.

would you please help me out figure out this?
thank you

Comment: Output is sent to the cron user's email. Are there any errors there?

Comment: Is there supposed to be a `;` before `rm $enc_file`?

Comment: we never setup user email for cron

Comment: and yes there should be semicolon before, but that didn't fix it

Comment: It's the default action.

Comment: Redirect the output to a file. Put `>>/tmp/cron.log 2>&1` at the end.

Comment: mail to is empty string, and we have different jobs that are running with no issues. but this one doesn't

Comment: Why do you set mailto to an empty string if you're trying to debug a problem?

Comment: i will try adding an output and see how it goes

Comment: it wasn't set by me, i am new developer and just trying to add new job (my first one ever)

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: oops, my bad. I'll try to move it to the correct section

Comment: after adding an output i figured that the file name was wrong. i corrected the issue. now it is working.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: But the filename was right when you ran it standalone? How did that happen?

Comment: i mistyped filename in crontab. when i reviewed the output, it stated that file does not exist. so i checked the crontab list and found the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my issue is just a typo, filename was wrong.
thanks to Barmer who helped me output cron log that let to fixing the problem

thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

cron uses a restricted environment to execute the scripts, [as mmccoo posted in other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135478/how-to-simulate-the-environment-cron-executes-a-script-with), you can check your script with the variables defined in the cron environment.

```
env - `cat ~/cronenv` /scripts/redmineEncrpt.sh
```

You can check if that produces any error.

Comment: He explained in comments that the actual problem was a typo in the crontab.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that comment